Theoretical question on the definition of conditional probability
From my understanding, the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$, $P(A|B)$, with $P(B) > 0$ is defined as:
$$
P(A|B) := \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}
$$
And I understand this definition, and the intuition behind it. However, I'm a little philosophically uncomfortable with how it's often used to compute $P(A \cap B)$. From the above definition, one can quickly prove:
$$
P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)
$$
By substituting in the formal definition of $P(A|B)$ into the right-hand side of the equation. However, for the above equation to be practically useful in computing $P(A \cap B)$, you'd need to be able to compute $P(B)$ and $P(A|B)$. But technically, since we've only defined $P(A|B)$ in terms of $P(A \cap B)$, then it seems we'd already have to know $P(A \cap B)$ in the first place!
I've seen several authors acknowledge this awkwardness, and usually its handled by saying you can often define a probability space in a way that it's intuitively clear enough what $P(A|B)$ is without recourse to the formal definition of $P(A|B)$. We know intuitively what $P(A|B)$ means: It's the probability of event $A$ occurring, supposing that event $B$ has occurred.
And while I can understand that, if that's case, it seems then that often we're really working with two definitions of conditional probability: The rigorous one often given, and a more "intuitive" definition that's useful when we want to avoid circularity when computing $P(A \cap B)$.
But part of the reason this way of acting makes me uncomfortable is because since we're not able to show these two "definitions" are logically equivalent, it seems it's perfectly possible $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(A|B)P(B)$ are two completely different values, if we use the "intuitive" definition of $P(A|B)$.
And I understand this situation shouldn't arise if we're careful in how we define our probability space, but I still find that such a situation can occur to be uncomfortable.

Not sure I follow. Can you provide an example in which $P(A|B) $ is somehow known independently?

Consider the following example @lulu: Suppose we have a jar filled with 10 balls. 3 are red, 7 are blue. Let B denote the event our first draw is a red ball, and A denote the event our second draw is a blue ball. Suppose we'd like to compute $P(A \cap B)$. Well $P(B) = 3/10$. And intuitively, $P(A|B) = 7/9$. So we'd like to say $P(A \cap B) = (3/10)(7/9)$.

@lulu And I've seen many other such examples/exercises where the reader is asked to compute a conditional probability by thinking intuitively about what it should be. These questions are usually concerned with discrete probability spaces that behave very nicely.

There is no need to refer to conditional probability at all there. By definition,  each draw sequence is equally probable and you can count those that begin red blue.

I agree that, often,  people lazily use short cuts that they might find hard to defend.  Is that your point?

@lulu Very fair point. I should be clear that example is not mine. It's from a textbook I'm reviewing from: https://minerva.it.manchester.ac.uk/~saralees/statbook2.pdf. Their example 1.4.2. But the way you describe is the one I would find more rigorously acceptable since there's no utilization of an intuitive understand of conditional probability.

@lulu But yes, although I might phrase it a little differently, I think I am getting at something like that idea. Certain approaches to solving a problem are taken that don't really seem to be rigorously definable. And I know some might think I'm being pedantic, but it seems like pedantic-ness is not necessarily a bad thing in math.

I don't think it's pedantic.  Especially in probability which, as you are probably aware,  it's littered with "paradoxical", or at least very unintuitive, results

At a minimum,  someone ought to be prepared to defend any computation they made by an appeal to intuition.

There are, in fact, famous examples where people have gotten the conditional probabilities wrong.

Here's one perspective that clarifies your two notions. Most probability spaces that are (implicitly) defined in an introductory class are some sort of composition (broadly construed) of Markov kernels.
Roughly speaking, you can view a Markov kernel as a "randomized function brings its own randomness". For example, the function $D$ mapping $k$ to "the sum of $k$ dice rolls" is such a function. Each time we apply the function, we roll new dice, so we don't have to worry about any secret dependence.
Say we first sample $N$ from a distribution on the natural numbers, roll that many dice, then take the sum. The result is $D(N)$. We might care about the probability ofsome event on the outcome, say $D(N) = s$, given that $N = k$. We can write that in two ways:

$P(D(N) = s \mid N = k)$.
$P(D(k) = s)$.

The first is the conditional probability in the $P(A \cap B)/P(A)$ sense. But the second is just a property of the $D$ Markov kernel. It's well defined even without the context of our probability space. You can view the "intuitive definition" of conditionals as being probabilities like the second bullet.
How do we know these two quantities are really the same? We construct the probability space in the first place to make them the same. When we formalize "generate $N$, roll that many dice, sum them" as a probability space, we want all of the first bullet's conditional probabilities to match what the random function $D$ says it should be in the second bullet.
This breaks the circularity. To compute, say, $P(N = k \cap D(N) = s)$, you can do two steps:

Use the definition of conditional probability to write it as $P(N = k) \cdot P(D(N) = s \mid N = k)$.
Apply the fact that we constructed our probability space in a way that makes the second factor equal to $P(D(k) = s)$.

Only the first step uses the rigorous definition. The second step in some sense uses your "intuitive definition". The whole point of Markov kernels is essentially to formalize that intuition.
(More formally, a Markov kernel maps each input to a distribution over outputs. But just as you can construct probability spaces where you've sampled i.i.d. variables from a given distribution, you can construct probability spaces where you've sampled from the output distributions of any Markov kernels you want to apply, all conditionally independently given their inputs. So strictly speaking, throughout my example, $D$ isn't a kernel itself, but rather a random function whose distribution is given by some kernel, say $\mathcal{D}$. The key quantity $P(D(k) = s)$ is typically written as $\mathcal{D}(k, \{s\})$ or similar.)

I'll definitely need to take some time to digest the concepts you're presenting, but at a high-level I think I understand what you're getting it. And I agree, this seems perfectly rigorous and reasonable, and makes me feel better about using the "intuitive" definition of conditional probability. Thanks!

What you say is correct. If you were just to find $P(A \cap B)$, even beginners can generally find it intuitively.
However, it introduces the concept of conditional probability more explicitly by writing it as $P(A\mid B).P(A)$.  But its real usefulness is developing Bayes' Theorem  to reverse conditional probabilities.
Because $P(A\cap B)=P(A \mid B).P(A)= P(B \mid A).P(B)$,
if we know $P(A\mid B)$, and need to find out $P(B\mid A)$,
we use Bayes' Theorem to invert the conditional probability

https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/10348 https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/10579 might help

Very fair points made. My thoughts would be this: Regarding reversing conditional probabilities, we would need to be able to compute $P(A|B)$. And if we're following in the spirit of my question, we should be able to do so without taking the shortcut of avoiding the actual definition of conditional probability and invoking intuition. But often times I see many texts do just this.
